# Can't access my Amazon instance with Remote Access

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

Last week I could connect without problems. But now I have a message with any of the following reasons.

1. Remote Access isnt enable on this server.
2. The Remote Server is turn off
3. The Remote Server isnt available on the network.

At first I thought was a password issue. But none of those options seem to be related to password. Also I can access the website I have running on my server. So the server is on and in the network.

So the only reason should be #1, but as I said I was able to access the server last week. Is there any chance Remote Access get disable? Or is possible that is a password issue but just didn't say for security reasons?

[image]

Comment: I would start by checking the firewall rules, within AWS this is the security groups that the server is in. I wonder if you might have limited remote admin access to your own IP address and maybe your IP address has changed in the last week?

Comment: @AlexHague well Im the only one with access to the aws account. But not the only with access to the server. So I think is more like it someone change something to the server than the security groups rules But I will take a look.

Comment: If you think a config change has been made to your server then I would start with using AWS Systems Manager to run powershell commands to verify that the configuration is correct. For this to work you'll need to have set an IAM Role for the instance that allows it to talk to Systems Manager. You can find documentation on Run Command here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html